# Finding Tax amount after fixed amount discount off

Tags: computational-mathematics

[image: percent off]

I'm trying write a function that calculates cart totals. I'm crosschecking above calculation which is correct.
I have a cart total which is 115.32 dollar. I apply 20 dollar fixed discount off. The sale tax is 9%. What I'm trying to find is to find the tax which is 7.87. Currently what I do is to calculate 9% of 95.32 dollar as the tax and subtract it to find subtotal - which is wrong. I need the correct formula that finds the values in the above picture.
What I know is the cart total which is 115.32 dollars, I know the fixed discount amount which is 20 dollar, I know the sales tax which is 9%. By using these I have to find the subtotal ot tax amount.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $$87.45 \times 1.09 = 95.3205$$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. First, you say "I'm trying to find (...) the tax", and later you say "I have to find the subtotal" - so which one is it?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct but I cannot mark is as the correct answer as in stackoverflow.